# How to avoid UniqueViolation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

My facebook-like application gives users the opportunity to delete unwanted messages from following users. For this purpose I created a `MicropostQuarantine` association between users and microposts: if such an association between a user and a micropost exists, then that user will not see that micropost in their feed. However, microposts will be visible also in a user's profile page, included those already in quarantine. So, if I removed a micropost from my feed and visited the profile page of that micropost's user, I would still see that micropost and have access to the remove button that would raise the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_micropost_quarantines_on_user_id_and_micropost_id"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, micropost_id)=(1, 300) already exists.
: INSERT INTO "micropost_quarantines" ("user_id", "micropost_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"):
```

The quarantine method in the microposts controller is simple:

```
def quarantine
  current_user.micropost_quarantines.create!(micropost_id: @micropost.id)
end
```

There is a `before_action :entitled_user, only: :quarantine` defined as follows:

```
def entitled_user
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to root_url unless (current_user == @micropost.user || current_user.following.include?(@micropost.user))
end
```

As you can see a user can only quarantine his own microposts and microposts from following users. In order to avoid UniqueViolation errors, I thought of adding some code to the `entitled_user` method, to check if the association already exists:

```
def entitled_user
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
  @quarantine = MicropostQuarantine.find_by(micropost_id: @micropost.id, user_id: current_user.id)
  redirect_to root_url unless (current_user == @micropost.user || current_user.following.include?(@micropost.user) || @quarantine.nil?)
end
```

However this does not work: the `entitled_user` method is ignored/bypassed by rails for some unknown reasons, I keep receiving the `UniqueViolation: ERROR` from ActiveRecord and the whole `unless` conditional is ignored, so that I would be able to quarantine microposts from non following users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we shoudn't use `unless` in complicated condition, try to the following:

```
redirect_to root_url if (current_user != @micropost.user && current_user.following.exclude?(@micropost.user)) || @quarantine.present?
```

---

Tips:

```
def entitled_user
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])

  if (current_user.id != @micropost.user_id && !current_user.following.exists?(@micropost.user_id)) ||
     current_user.micropost_quarantines.exists?(micropost_id: @micropost.id)

    redirect_to root_path and return
  end
end
```

- Using `:exists?` (SQL side) is more efficient than `:include?` (Ruby side)
- Using `@micropost.user_id` instead of `@micropost.user` because we don't need instance `@user`, so we don't need to do like this:

`SELECT (*) FROM users WHERE id = #{@micropost.user_id}`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Try to put `debugger` in method `entitled_user `

Comment: With your solution the server log says `Filter chain halted as :entitled_user rendered or redirected`

Comment: My original version of `entitled_user` works, without the part of code that would check if the micropost is already in quarantine. When I add it everything breaks down.

Comment: I do not know why but to my understanding Rails seems to have problems in processing 3 conditionals, so I left `entitled_user` as it was and tried to create a specific `before_action` for the third conditional, and now it works.

Comment: I've got it. Please check my final answer